# Average height of Shetland Island residents

Tags: data-request, medical, europe, demographics

I am looking for the average height of Shetland Island residents by gender.

I am sure it must be out there but for all the data sets with height by location, I have not found the Shetland Islands broken out separately. Weight would be a bonus.

It seems that the average size of almost all animals in the Shetlands are small. Not just the famous Shetland Sheepdogs and Shetland Ponies, but even sheep, pigs, ducks, etc. I am curious if it is completely uncorrelated with the size of humans in that location.

Comment: Population is 22k and 7.5k are in the capital city. You can probably go with a measuring stick on a week's vacation to get a statistical sample ;)

Comment: @philshem Sounds like a nice vacation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you much about the average height of a Shetlander. However, I can tell you that I was born and raised in Shetland and that I am roughly 175cm tall. I am a 16-year-old boy as I am writing this.

Comment: Thanks for the data point and welcome to Open Data. Cheers.